# Automatic click button when click other buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(IBAction)buttonAnimator:(id)sender
{
    [self.activityIndicator setAlpha:1];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
- (IBAction)buttonInfo:(id)sender
{


}
```

How can i click `buttonInfo` automatically when I click `buttonAnimator`. `buttonInfo` has got push segue event I just want to start animating then click `buttonInfo`.

`buttonInfo:` empty first i try to both of them some button animation and pass other view with push segue because i use navigator i have to use push segue when i use 1 button animation did not start waiting get data loading than i try to use 2 button first of all im starting animation than im getting data but im clicking 2 button i have to click automatically second button

Comment: What's the problem with this : `[self buttonInfo:nil];`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because now iOS do this automatically please close topic

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
-(IBAction)buttonAnimator:(id)sender
{
    [self.activityIndicator setAlpha:1];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];
}

- (IBAction)buttonInfo:(id)sender
{


}
```

OR:

```
-(IBAction)buttonAnimator:(id)sender
{
    [self.activityIndicator setAlpha:1];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self buttonInfo:sender];    
}

- (IBAction)buttonInfo:(id)sender
{
   // do stuff here
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];
}
```

Depending on how exactly the segue with the ID `"MySegue"` is defined in the storyboard editor, with the second alternative you may end up performing the segue twice when the user presses the info button and when that issues the action `buttonInfo:` too.

The first alternative will not perform the processing within buttonInfo. So in the end this may be your solution:

```
-(IBAction)buttonAnimator:(id)sender
{
    [self.activityIndicator setAlpha:1];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self buttonInfo:sender];   
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];
}

- (IBAction)buttonInfo:(id)sender
{
   // do stuff here

}
```